# Inheritance TypeScript with exported class and modules

Tags: node.js, inheritance, typescript

I'm getting crazy with inheritance using typescript. I don't know why but it cannot resolve the class I want to inherit.

*lib/classes/Message.class.**ts***

```
///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>

export module SharedCommunication {
    export class Message{
         // Stuff
    }
}
```

*lib/classes/ValidatorMessage.class.**ts***

```
///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='Message.class.ts'/>

export module SharedCommunication { 
    export class ValidatorMessage extends Message{
        private  _errors;
    }    
}
```

Message cannot be resolved. I tried SharedCommunication.Message too but it's the same. I reference the class so I don't understand at all what's going on. Do you have any idea?

I tried without the module (two class without be in any module) but it's the same. I need to export the class (and the module if I use it) to get them from another node_module: typescript.api, which I use to load the class and use it in node.

*lib/message.js*

```
var Message = require('./classes/Message.class.ts');

module.exports = Message.SharedCommunication.Message;
```

What's the trick here? Because I have source code on the same project in a different folder working with inheritance, without module or export. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ValidatorMessage.class.ts should look like this:

```
///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>

import message = require('./Message.class');

export module SharedCommunication { 
    export class ValidatorMessage extends message.SharedCommunication.Message {
        private  _errors;
    }
}
```

It's usually redundant to have a single `export module` at the top level of a file since the file itself constitutes a namespace anyway.

Bill mentioned this in your other question, but I'd again caution on using RequireTS if you're just starting out with TypeScript - it sounds pretty unmature and is likely to introduce a lot of confusion.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I found it few minutes before your answer, but I still don't understand why the reference is useless here.
I don't really understand your point of view about export module. I need to export it to get access to it somewhere else.
I use typescript.api as TypeScript file loader, works well. I need it, and it works unlike require-typescript.

Comment: I'm trying to write up some documentation on this. It's admittedly confusing. The samples included with the TypeScript git repo do a good job showing some of the normal patterns for program structure.

Comment: Yeah but my friend who are used to use TS and has already wrote a lot of script with it don't use the *import* but only references and it works well ^^ Thank you for your help, I'm looking forward about TS documentation.

Comment: I have another problem with this source code. I want to use it on the browser now but it's not working because of the call to require(). Require is undefined. I tried to write it: require = function(file){ var files = file.split('/'); file = files[files.length - 1].replace('.class', ''); return exports[file] || window[file]; }

Answer (score 1):

Take out the export from the mododule declaration:

```
module SharedCommunication 
{ 
    export class ValidatorMessage extends message.SharedCommunication.Message 
    {
        private  _errors;
    }
}
```